# GTM - multiple buttons with same ID

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I am creating a new Google Tag Manager tag for GA, which triggers when element with class "button" has been clicked. All of the buttons(5 of them) do exactly the same thing, only difference is their location.

I would like to set tag's Label or Value equal to index(0-4) of the button clicked.

Probably I should create new custom JS variable, but I could not figure out how it should look like.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, probably you should. What have you tried out in terms of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to get an answer from Google's product forum.

You can get the "nth" number of the button on the page with a Custom JavaScript var:

```
function() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i += 1) {
    if (els[i] === {{Click Element}}) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Link to original answer: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/mrJ9NQsaS8Q;context-place=forum/tag-manager

Thank you Mr. Simo Ahava!